# Android how to remove item when uncheck checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

i manage to do when my checkbox inchecked my textview will append the text from checkbox, else when the checkbox uncheck the text will remove. how to remove from arraylist when the checkbox is unchecked.

```
public class condimentlist extends BaseAdapter {

    LayoutInflater mInflater;

    private ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public ArrayList<Integer> getPositions() {
        return positions;
    }

    public condimentlist() {
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return CondimentList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.condimentlistview_details, null);
        }
        condcb  = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.condcb);
        final TextView tremark = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Tremark);

        final TextView condimenttext=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.condimenttext);
        Condiment myObj = CondimentList.get(position);
        condimenttext.setText("" +myObj.getCondimentName());

        condcb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                      @Override
                                      public void onClick(View v) {
                                          String i = condimenttext.getText().toString();
                                          Toast.makeText(getActivity(),i,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                          SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
                                          SharedPreferences.Editor editor1 = pref.edit();
                                          if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
                                              data.add(i);
                                              String array[] = data.toArray(new String[0]);
                                              for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                                                        remark.append(String.valueOf(array[j]));
                                              }
                                          } else {
                                              SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("checkbox1", 0);
                                              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                                              editor.putBoolean(((CheckBox) v).getText().toString(), false);
                                              editor.commit();
                                              data.remove(position)

                                          }

                                      }
                                  }
        );
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: just do  `yourarrayList.remove(position)`

Comment: @Redman thanks , i put ----data.remove(positions); ---- in my else statement but it no work

Comment: what is the value of positions?

Comment: i edited my question this is how i get my position

Comment: add `notifyDataSetChanged()`   after removing items

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 1 i get this error when i put this command -------data.remove(position);----- the position is out of my size

Comment: are you having only 1 item in the list?

Comment: 3 item in my list

Comment: according to error , you are having only 1 item in array list but you are trying to remove second item, check once if you are removing from other array list